# How to get all table names with a regex in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I need to build a regular expression for C# in order to capture all table names that are after 'from' keywords in select clauses. For example

```
.
.
.
SELECT field1, field2
FROM table1
WHERE condition1
.
.
.
SELECT field3, field4
FROM table2
WHERE condition2
.
.
.
```

There are multiple select clauses in the files that I try to read, and there can be any character between select and from(including new lines, ':', '_' and any other character). 
How should I construct my regex in order to get all table names?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I' ve found a way to get all table names.

```
\s*SELECT[^;]*FROM\s*(?<key>[^\n]*)
```

This might help someone on some day.
Thanks

Comment: When I try `SELECT[\D|\d]*FROM (?<key>[^ \n]*)`, it finds one match that starts with the first select and all the way down to the last from. I instead want it to match all selects and return all of their table names.

Comment: Give this site a try, always helps me when figuring out RegExes http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @Charleh that is for Javascript regexes. For .NET you should use [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net)

Comment: You shouldn't try because this is too complicated. What about derived tables, CTEs, EXISTS clauses, CROSS APPLY, and so on? Submit the queries for estimated execution plan and mine the resulting data.

Comment: @ErikE can you give a simple example please?

Comment: Is there always just one table?

Comment: @m.buettner well, depends if you want to pay $10/$20 or not :). The JS one will get you most of the way there (depends how complex your regex is I suppose). Doesn't .NET let you choose the Regex flavour (i.e. use JS regex engine)?

Comment: @Charleh you can use enough features of RegexHero for free to use it for testing. Even if not, you are choosing one of the least capable engines to test for one of the most capable ones. You could at least use [rubular](http://rubular.com) or something. And I am not aware that you can choose the engine in .NET.

Comment: Fair enough - I'll have a look at the free bits, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless all queries have only one table and there is no funny business with comments, using regular expressions for this is a losing proposition. Instead:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON;

--All your queries here
```

See [set showplan_all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735.aspx) docs.

When I say that the regular expression is going to be complicated, this is what I mean. These are only *some* of the considerations:

- You'll have to detect the start of quoted strings: `"`, `'`, and `[` and ignore all characters inside until terminated properly. Do not terminate if the end character is doubled up (i.e., `'this is ''fun'', he said'` does not stop after `is`).
- You'll have to exclude single line comments `--` that aren't inside of quotes, and terminate them at the next CRLF. Quote marks inside comments do not start strings as usual.
- You'll have to exclude multi-line comments (starting with `/*`) that aren't inside of quotes or inside of a single line comment, and then skip over everything else except the terminator, `*/`. In your regex, be sure to escape the `*` character with a backslash `\`.
- You'll have to then find valid `FROM` clauses with proper word boundaries (no false match on column names `SelfRom` or `AfroMonkey`, for example).
- To properly terminate the FROM clause, you have to stop capturing when you see any keyword including `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`, and `WITH`; and since SQL queries aren't required to have the semicolon terminator `;` then you'll also have to terminate at `SELECT`, `DBCC`, `SET`, `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP` and so on and so forth.
- But even the previous two points are not really enough by themselves, because what if your query looks like this:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM
     MyTable T
     INNER JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM YourTable Y WHERE Active = 1
     ) X ON T.ID = Y.ID
     INNER JOIN AnotherTable A
        ON X.AID = A.AID
  ```

  Now you have to parse parentheses and NOT stop capturing your FROM clause when you see any of those keywords. And you have to keep track of how many parentheses deep you are and keep ignoring until you're that many out. And finally, what do you do with those, because a derived table is just like a table--do you want the full text of the derived table or just the tables inside that?

To do all that, you can't just start matching at the first valid `FROM` in the text, because this could be inside of quotes or comments. You have to match all the text starting at the beginning, because that is the only way with Regex to ensure you don't find a match where you shouldn't.

Here's what I came up with that just tries to handle **comments**. Not even quotes. And it only goes as far as finding the *from* clause, not what's inside it. Plus, we have to prevent parentheses from capturing so we don't have an awful mess when examining our capturing groups for the actual FROM clauses.

```
(?:(?:-(?!-)|/(?!\*)|f(?!rom)|[^-f/])|--[^\n]*\n|/\*(?:\*/)*\*/)*from()
```

And it's probably rife with errors and I'd have to rethink the whole thing once I played with it a bit and all in all, it would be a gigantic waste of time.

I think you are underestimating how difficult such a thing will be to accomplish well. But there's a perfectly reliable solution! The one I gave above: let SQL Server parse everything for you. You can parse the returned plan easily because it is structured in a way that makes it easy.

Answer (score 1):

To start I'd say check out this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

check out a regex like this: `((?<=FROM )[^\s]+)`

This regex will start reading directly after `"FROM "` (including whitespace) and stops reading at the first whitespace `(^\s)`

if you try something like this

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"((?<=FROM )[^\s]+)")
{
    string output = m.Value;
}
```

EDIT:

I'm not 100% sure about this regex. If you have a newline character at the end of your name this woudl probably do the job better: `@"((?<=FROM)[^\n]+))` but you should probably trim the output as there might be a whitespace at the start of your output string.

Comment: FORM !== FROM my dear chap

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "select name from Table1 where id =2";
var pattern = @"from\s*(.*?)\s*where"; // where car= is the first delimiter and ; is the second one
var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Comment: And what about comments that say "from"? Disaster.

Comment: Multiple queries together will not be handled right--the result will span all of them.